Jetpack Compose Coil-AsyncImage: Howto refresh/reload the image when the image URI does not change
I use AsyncImage to load an image from a remote location.
Use case is a profile picture which is taken from the cam then uploaded to a remote database and then it shall be refreshed in the UI.
Now it can happen that the image changes but the URI remains the same.
I then trigger a recomposition, but the image remains the same.
I see nothing happening in the loading/success/error callbacks.
I tried to use an ImageRequest as model instead of the URI and tried to disable all caches there but this resulted in an error.
When i try another URI instead the Image changes.
So question here is how to make the AsyncImage refresh also if the URI does not change
[EDIT / Resolved]
Workaround is to add a dummy image with a different URI before loading the image again, but clearing disk and memory cache is also required

The whole idea of an ID (and an URI respectively) is to uniquely describe something. Allowing two images to use the same URI breaks that contract and should be avoided

Sure, that's the definition of URI, but what if you have a backend that delivers you always (and you have no chance to get that changed, because you're not the owner?):
server.address/{user_id}/user_image.png
But i'm ok with my workaround.
